# NGINX Rewrites for a site move

Tags: regex, url, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a problem we need to move our site to another software.

We have the following URL setup:

```
Downloads / Resources
Original:
https://www.website.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=47

New:
https://www.website.com/resources/flight-update-red.47/

Forum
Original:
https://www.website.com/gen-chat-213/

New:
https://www.website.com/forums/gen-chat.213/

Thread
Original:
https://www.website.com/gen-chat-213/8281-connect-probs.html

New:
https://www.website.com/threads/connect-probs.8281/
```

I tried this for the forum section:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)-$/ /forums/$1.$2/ last;
```

But no luck could someone please help,

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This works based on your examples.

```
   location / {
      # Downloads / Resources
      if ($args ~* "id=(\d+)") {
        set $id $1;
        set $args '';
        rewrite ^/downloads\.php(.*)$ /resources/flight-update-red.$id/ permanent;
      }

      # Forum
      rewrite ^/([a-z-]+)-(\d+)/$ /forums/$1.$2/ permanent;

      # Thread
      rewrite ^/[a-z-]+-\d+\/(\d+)-(.*)\.html$ /threads/$2.$1/ permanent;
   }
```

Comment: MISAKE SORRY - Could you help me with these also 

PAGES FROM THREADS:
`https://www.website.com/gen-chat-213/8281-connect-probs-2.html
https://www.website.com/gen-chat-213/8281-connect-probs-3.html
https://www.website.com/gen-chat-213/8281-connect-probs-4.html
`

                                                                                           ...................TO................................ 

`https://www.website.com/threads/connect-probs.8281/page-2
https://www.website.com/threads/connect-probs.8281/page-3
https://www.website.com/threads/connect-probs.8281/page-4
`

Comment: Thank you very much Miguel,  your help was fantastic.

Comment: Try this `rewrite ^/[a-z-]+-\d+\/(\d+)-([a-z-]+)-(\d+)\.html$ /threads/$2.$1/page-$3/ permanent;`

Comment: This Works to Maguel!  THANK YOU.    I had to put the pages Rewrite before the threads rewrite or it would not work.

Comment: Hi @Miguel Thank you for your help but could you help me with a few more REGEX Nginx rewrites please. OLD URL:  `https://www.website.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=4798` . TO `https://www.website.com/index.php?resources/4798/ `  ......   AND ALSO COULD YOU HELP WITH - ....... OLD URL:   `https://www.website.com/showthread.php?t=4449128` ....  TO .....  `https://www.website.com/index.php?threads/4449128/`

Comment: Thank you @Miguel Mota  I appreciate all your help!

Comment: @MarkDavis create a new question and send me the link

Comment: Just made a new one and added you to it [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44750493/nginx-rewrites-dynamic-pages[/link]