# NGINX Rewrites dynamic pages

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I need some help with nginx regex rewrites.

THIS

```
https://www.website.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=4798
```

TO

```
https://www.website.com/index.php?resources/4798/
```

THIS

```
https://www.website.com/showthread.php?t=4449128
```

TO

```
https://www.website.com/index.php?threads/4449128/
```

THIS (TRICKY ONE).

```
https://www.website.com/forumdisplay.php?f=12&prefixid=8
```

TO

```
https://www.website.com/forums/pc-probs.12/?prefix_id=8
```

Thank you all for your help.

@Miguel Mota

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This works based on your examples.

```
location / {

    # A
    if ($args ~* "id=(\d+)") {
        set $id $1;
        set $args '';

        rewrite ^/downloads\.php(.*)$ /index.php?resources/$id/ permanent;
    }

    # B
    if ($args ~* "t=(\d+)") {
        set $t $1;
        set $args '';

        rewrite ^/showthread.php(.*)$ /index.php?threads/$t/ permanent;
    }

    # C
    if ($args ~* "prefixid=(\d+)") {
        set $pfid  $1;
    }
    if ($args ~* "f=(\d+)") {
        set $f $1;
        set $args '';
        rewrite ^/forumdisplay.php(.*)$ /forums/pc-probs.$f/?prefix_id=$pfid/ permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Miguel,  I am testing that now.  also -  if #C /forums/pc-probs  is equal to something else,   /forums/tesco.8  or /forums/otherforum.47  or /forums/another-forum.48  and so on....  can this be dynamic

Comment: @MarkDavis where is `pc-probs` in original url? is it a query param?

Comment: #A and #B are working,  I am getting a javascript error when I use #B though on xenforo.

Comment: pc-probs is a name of a forum that is generated by the software.